# ionic v2 build android Apk error

Tags: android, ionic-framework, build

i'm using ionic framework version 2.2.3 , cordova 7.1.0 and node 8.9.2 
when i'm running ionic build android ( after adding the paltform to the project ) .ANDROID_HOME and JAVA_HOME are well set .i'm getting the error below :

[image: build error]

Comment: you need to open sdk manager and agree to the terms and conditions..

Comment: actually , i'm trying to update SDK tools ; will that resolve the issue ?

Comment: yes.. it says so in the error message.. YOu will have to accept them once you install/update through the SDK manager

Comment: ok thanks , still waiting :)

Comment: that problem was resolved , but now when i'm trying to ruunig it into an android device , just a white screen appears

Comment: A different issue. You may have to debug

Comment: in config.xml file i have set these variable to :    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
    <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="22" />
    <preference name="android-maxSdkVersion" value="22" />  , i haven't understand  <engine name="android" spec="^6.3.0" /> role  and should i modify cordova-android": "^6.3.0", in tsconfig file to the situable android version ?

Comment: that is the [cordova-android](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/) platform version.. that will get modified if you ever update it.